# How do I modify the value of a multidimensional array from a function?

Tags: node.js

Trying to make a tic tac toe program where the last 2 moves are randomized through the nextMove function. However when I try to implement the move for either team, the value in the array does not change.

Here's my code:

```
let board = [["X", "O", "O"], ["X", "O", "O"], ["_", "_", "O"]];

function randomizeInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function nextMove() {
  let randomInt = randomizeInt(10);
  if (randomInt <= 5) {
    board[2][0][0] = "X";
    board[2][1][0] = "O";
  }
  else {
    board[2][0][0] = "O";
    board[2][1][0] = "X";
  }
}

function displayBoard() {
  console.log("| " + board[0][0][0] + " | "
    + board[0][1][0] + " | " + board[0][2][0]
    + " |");
  console.log("| " + board[1][0][0] + " | "
    + board[1][1][0] + " | " + board[1][2][0]
    + " |");
  console.log("| " + board[2][0][0] + " | "
    + board[2][1][0] + " | " + board[2][2][0]
    + " |");
}

function winnerCheck() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let ans = null;


    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        ans = board[0][0][0] + board[0][1][0] + board[0][2][0];
        break;
      case 1:
        ans = board[1][0][0] + board[1][1][0] + board[1][2][0];
        break;
      case 2:
        ans = board[2][0][0] + board[2][1][0] + board[2][2][0];
        break;
      case 3:
        ans = board[0][0][0] + board[1][0][0] + board[2][0][0];
        break;
      case 4:
        ans = board[0][1][0] + board[1][1][0] + board[2][1][0];
        break;
      case 5:
        ans = board[0][2][0] + board[1][2][0] + board[2][2][0];
        break;
      case 6:
        ans = board[0][0][0] + board[1][1][0] + board[2][2][0];
        break;
      case 7:
        ans = board[2][0][0] + board[1][1][0] + board[0][2][0];
        break;
    }

    if (ans === "XXX") {
      console.log("X is the winner");
    }
    else if (ans === "OOO") {
      console.log("O is the winner");
    }
  }
}


nextMove();
displayBoard();
winnerCheck();
```

I've tried directly changing the values through assigning them to either X or O however nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading and assigning values to a tri-dimensional array, but your array is only two-dimensional.

It still gives you proper values when you read them, but it doesn't work when you are trying to assign something to it. You should remove the last "[0]" every time you used the "board" array.